# How to get theme color inside the widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'AnApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      home: MainWidget()
    );
  }
}
```

So I have set `primarySwatch` color to `blueGrey`.
How can I access this color inside the `MainWidget` class?

I want to set a background the same as the `AppBar` color.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I'm not sure if there exist a way to use `primarySwatch` inside widget like that but if you are looking for `AppBar` color, it is actually the `primaryColor` and you can get it using

```
Color color = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please create the AppTheme class and setup dark and light theme

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
   darkTheme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
   themeMode: theme.isDarkMode ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,

  home: SplashScreen(),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure. If you use CupertinoApp i think it would be more appropriate to use `CupertinoTheme.of(context)`

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

```
color: Theme.of(context).primarySwatch;
```

OR

you can change the primaryswatch color in main theme class instead of changing in your class by -

Clicking on ctrl + primarySwatch, You will be Headed to theme_data page and there you can change your theme color according to your convience.